# System.lineSeparator() doesn't exist in android

Tags: java, android

`System.lineSeparator()` is not available when I am doing my Android development. I had to use the older version `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead.

Can anyone explain to me why is that? Is it because the Android SDK is not using Java 7?

Comment: Do you definitely have to use this method to complete your task?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, `System.lineSeparator()` this is a JAVA 1.7 feature.
`System.getProperty("line.separator")` is the correct way to do it pre 1.7

There is an open bug on the oracle site where `System.lineSeparator()` has not been marked with @Since 1.7.
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7094275

> "The new static method lineSeparator() on java.lang.System class is
> new in java 1.7, so should have the @since 1.7 annotation present in
> the javadoc."