# System.getProperty("line.separator") not working - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Currently I have a code where I retrieve the website plain text and store it inside a text file. I managed to do that but when I want to enter a new line in the text file it doesn't work.

My result

```
This is the article titleThis is the starting of the first paragraph
```

What I want

```
This is the article title
This the starting of the first paragraph
```

My source code

```
public void storeHTML(Context context, ArrayList<String> storeHTML, String address) {
    try {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/voicethenews");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }

        address = address.substring(address.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        File gpxfile = new File(root, address + ".txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);

        //FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(gpxfile);
        //BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream));

        for(int i = 0; i < storeHTML.size(); i++) {

            //bufferedWriter.write(storeHTML.get(i));
            //bufferedWriter.newLine();
            writer.append(storeHTML.get(i) + System.lineSeparator());


        }

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've tried multiple code and solution but it's still not working.

Comment: If you are writing HTML to a file, you need to use `<br />` rather than a line separator of the system

Comment: I have already extracted the plain text by title and paragraph and store it in `ArrayList<String> storeHTML`, Does `<br/> still applicable to that ?

Comment: You are probably getting bitten by this issue:
[System.lineSeparator() doesn't exist in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150092/system-lineseparator-doesnt-exist-in-android)

Comment: You are probably getting bitten by this issue: [System.lineSeparator() doesn't exist in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150092/system-lineseparator-doesnt-exist-in-android)

Comment: You are probably getting bitten by this issue: [System.lineSeparator doesn't exist in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150092/system-lineseparator-doesnt-exist-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the actual reason why it doesn't display as I intended.

The reason why it doesn't seem to work in the first place it was due to me opening the text file using the default notepad. When open using other text editor such as notepad++, the output in the text file was writen as intended.

Answer (score 0):

If you get detail from HTML. So, let use `<br>`, instead of `<br \>`

This is an example code to add text to a textView `b`

```
b.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + st + "</b>" + "<br/>" + cursor.getString(1)));
```

Reference: [How do i add a new line in html format in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342042/how-do-i-add-a-new-line-in-html-format-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably addressing the exact same issue you are having:

[System.lineSeparator() doesn't exist in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150092/system-lineseparator-doesnt-exist-in-android)

There was a bug in the pre 1.7 SDKs where you would have to call the environmental variable directly.